# Trying to search products in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using 3 tier architecture to develop website. I need to develop search functionality to show products based on what user type in search bar. When I debug, I see search value is not passing to ProductBL's GetProductInfo page. 
Here is code:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchString = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
        Product product = new Product();

        product.ProductName = txtSearch.Text.Trim();

        ProductBL.GetProductInfo(searchString);
    }
```

ProductBL Code for GetProductInfo method:

```
public static DataTable GetProductInfo(string searchString)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Products] where ProductName like @SearchString and Visible = 1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchString", SqlDbType.Text).Value = searchString;
        return DbUtility.GetRecordsInDataTable(cmd);
    }
```

Gridview page:

```
Search:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="Search" runat="server" OnClick="Search" />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" CssClass="footable" 
        OnRowDeleting="DeleteRecord"  EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." 
          CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"  />
```

Kindly Help me with this

Comment: *I am not able to pass search string value to Business Logic* What does it mean? search String not getting here? `GetProductInfo(string searchString)`

Comment: @Div Here is the error. The parameterized query '(@SearchString nvarchar(4000))SELECT * FROM [Products] where Pro' expects the parameter '@SearchString', which was not supplied.

Comment: Change like this: "SELECT * FROM [Products] where ProductName like '%"+ SearchString +"' and Visible = 1";

Comment: @Orion: did you checked your wildcard conditions `like @SearchString` I think its wrong. have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Comment: @Div nad I am not getting value here itself. string searchString = Request.QueryString["ProductName"]; here when i debug, the searchString value is null. Whatever the value i put inside textbox, it is not showing up here.

Comment: Instead of  string searchString = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];  do    string searchString = txtSearch.Text;  Query seems okay to me.

Comment: @Orion *When I debug, I see search value is not passing to ProductBL's GetProductInfo page* see this, and now you're asking for *I am not getting value here itself. string searchString = Request.QueryString["ProductName"]; here when i debug*

Comment: @Orion, Sami is right use  `searchString = txtSearch.Text`

Comment: @Orion: do the steps as suggested by Sami.

Comment: @nad, thanks. I think Orion would solve the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
string searchString = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
```

to

```
string searchString = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
```

Because you are sending `searchString` to function as:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ProductBL.GetProductInfo(searchString);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This works for me. There is no error. But the grid view displaying all values. I just want to display the product which is entered in textbox.

Comment: Did you try, SELECT * FROM [Products] where ProductName = @SearchString

Comment: Make you sure, GridView is not being re-bind again somewhere in your code, after search.

Comment: GridView1.DataSource = ProductBL.GetProducts();
            GridView1.DataBind();   Its showing all products

Comment: Tried above mentioned code. It show there are no records to display

Comment: Udpate query use like instead of =

Answer (score 0):

You have not set your query properly. First try checking your query in `SQL` editor.

The issue lies here.

```
like @SearchString
```

Change it to something like below

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] where ProductName like '%SearchString%' and Visible = 1
```

IF there will be records in the `Products` table then it will fetch through the query.

Also have a look at how to use Wildcards

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/98434

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here seems like your wildcard condition is wrong:
Has per comment you've to change your query like following.

```
 string query = "SELECT * FROM [Products] where ProductName like where name like '%' + replace(SearchString, '%', '[%]') + '%' and Visible = 1";
```

Here your query seems like : `select * from tablename where Column like '%[%]%'`

It'll give you more appropriate result.

Comment: Yes. There was a problem with wildcard condition. Thanks a lot